How to define a type for an object with and id
I need to define an interface that reflects this part of a response:
"responses": {
    "accepted": [],
    "declined": [],
    "messages": {
        "id1": {
            "profile": "",
            "message": "Lorem ipsum"
        },
        "id2": {
            "profile": "",
            "message": "Lorem ipsum"
        }
     }

So far I have defined the responses like this:
export interface Response {
    accepted: string[],
    declined: string[],
    messages: Messages
}

How do I define the Messages interface properly?
export interface Messages {
    profile: string,
    message: string,
}


You forgot to add string keys to messages, and rename Messages to Message to reflect that this is one object:
export interface Response {
    accepted: string[],
    declined: string[],
    messages: Record<string, Message>
}
export interface Message {
    profile: string,
    message: string,
}


You can create a type for it like this
export interface Response {
    accepted: string[],
    declined: string[],
    messages:  Record<string, Messages>
}

export interface Messages {
    profile: string,
    message: string,
}

Here Record<string, Messages> shows that key will be type of string and value will be type of Messages
